# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
if let data = data{
   do{
       let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
       print(parsedData["result"]!)
       let result = parsedData["result"]  as! Int
       if(parsedData["result"] == 0 ){
           print(result)
           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Favorite Added", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
           }))
           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
    }catch{
       print(error)
    }
}
```

> here is giving error of Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int' 
>   the image of this error is also attached

[image: error]

Comment: you can easily do like this `if result == 0 {`

Comment: @V_rohit No you can't, see the crash message

Comment: @vadian.. understand Sir.... I read your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this code is working for me

```
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
                let key = "result"
                let value = parsedData[key] as? Int ?? Int(parsedData[key] as? String ?? "")
                print(value!)
                let result = value!

                if(result == 0){
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two serious issues:

1. The error occurs because a dictionary value of a `[String:Any]` dictionary is `Any` which is unspecified.
2. The preceding crash clearly indicates that the value for key `parsedData` is a **string**, not a number

You got two options, first conditional downcast to `String` and check for `"0"`

```
if let result = parsedData["result"] as? String, result == "0" { ...
```

or convert the string to `Int` and check for the numeric `0`

```
if let result = parsedData["result"] as? String,  let intResult = Int(result), intResult == 0 { ...
```

**In both cases use optional bindings to safely unwrap the optionals**

Comment: this is really helpful for me thank you for this explanation

Comment: but after do this print(result) give me nil value

Comment: Please create a string `String(data: parsedData, encoding: .utf8)!`, `print` it and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell go for `String` first then convert that string 
check something like this

```
guard let result = parsedData["result"] as! String else {return}
if parsedData["result"] == "0"{
}
```

Comment: let result = parsedData["result"] as? String
                    print(result) 
after doing this result give me nil

Comment: can you put 
let result = parsedData["result"]  as! String

Answer (score 0):

First convert data as int, check with this code..

```
 let num = data as! Int
 if num == 1{
 print(success)
  }
```